# Error message when creating new pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am looking for some help understanding an error message I am getting when trying to create a new Azure Data Factory pipeline.
I am attempting this via PowerShell:
     New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline $df -File C:\projects\bldatalake\data\Auto_ADFpipeline_scheduled_09.json

The error message and relevant dataset defining JSON are down below.
I do not understand what a "Dataset Scope" is in the context.
Please enlighten me!
Thank you!
Eric

New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: PipelineScopeDataSetInScheduledPipelineNotSupportedForSubscription
Error Message: Dataset Scope in Scheduled Pipeline not supported for this subscription. Please contact the Azure Data Factory team
if you would like to use this feature: https://azure.microsoft.com/support/options/
Request Id: 782cee8f-ada0-4df2-99ef-60c9e3b7b01c
Timestamp (Utc):05/01/2017 17:32:35
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline $df -File C:\projects\bldatalake\data\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactories.NewAzureDataFactoryPipelineCommand

The pipeline definition JSON is:

```
 {
  "name": "AUTO-CopyPipeline-ASQL-ADLS-636292567401603805",
  "properties": {
    "description": "bLoyal ASQL to ADLS pipeline",
    "activities": [{
  "type": "Copy",
  "typeProperties": {
    "source": {
      "type": "SqlSource",
      "sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('select * from [dbo].[ProductBrandRevisions] where [Updated] >= \'{ 0:yyyy - MM - dd HH: mm}\' AND [Updated] < \'{ 1:yyyy - MM - dd HH: mm}\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
    },
    "sink": {
      "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink",
      "writeBatchSize": 0,
      "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
    }
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "AUTO-InputDatasets-[636292567401603805]-[ProductBrandRevisions]"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "AUTO-OutputDatasets-[636292567401603805]-[ProductBrandRevisions]"
    }
  ],
  "policy": {
    "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
    "concurrency": 1,
    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
    "style": "StartOfInterval",
    "retry": 3,
    "longRetry": 0,
    "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
  },
  "scheduler": {
    "frequency": "Day",
    "interval": 1
  },
  "name": "Activity-0-[636292567401603805]-[ProductBrandRevisions]"
}
],
    "start": "2017-05-01T17:42:20.1603805Z",
    "end": "2067-05-01T17:32:20.1603805Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "bllogadf_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled",
    "datasets": [{
  "name": "AUTO-InputDatasets-[636292567401603805]-[ProductBrandRevisions]",
  "properties": {
    "structure": [{"name": "Id", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Updated", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "EntitySyncProfileId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "EntityId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "EntityUid", "type": "Guid"},{"name": "ExternalId", "type": "String"},{"name": "ParentEntityId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Status", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Error", "type": "String"},{"name": "CurrentRevision", "type": "Int64"},{"name": "LastAckRevision", "type": "Int64"},{"name": "FirstUpdateSinceAck", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "LastAckUpdated", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "AssociatedEntitiesRevision", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Uid", "type": "Guid"},{"name": "Created", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "CreatedLocal", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "Datestamp", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "TransientBatchId", "type": "Int32"}],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureSqlTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "Source-SQLAzure-multi-table",
    "typeProperties": {
      "tableName": "[dbo].[ProductBrandRevisions]"
    },
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Day",
      "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
  }
},{
  "name": "AUTO-OutputDatasets-[636292567401603805]-[ProductBrandRevisions]",
  "properties": {
    "structure": [{"name": "Id", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Updated", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "EntitySyncProfileId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "EntityId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "EntityUid", "type": "Guid"},{"name": "ExternalId", "type": "String"},{"name": "ParentEntityId", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Status", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Error", "type": "String"},{"name": "CurrentRevision", "type": "Int64"},{"name": "LastAckRevision", "type": "Int64"},{"name": "FirstUpdateSinceAck", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "LastAckUpdated", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "AssociatedEntitiesRevision", "type": "Int32"},{"name": "Uid", "type": "Guid"},{"name": "Created", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "CreatedLocal", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "Datestamp", "type": "Datetime"},{"name": "TransientBatchId", "type": "Int32"}],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
    "linkedServiceName": "Destination-DataLakeStore-ifh",
    "typeProperties": {
      "fileName": "ProductBrandRevisions.txt",
      "folderPath": "ASqlImport",
      "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat",
        "columnDelimiter": "\t",
        "firstRowAsHeader": true
      }
    },
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Day",
      "interval": 1
    },
    "external": false,
    "policy": {}
  }
}
]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try creating the datasets first then the pipeline?

Comment: I will try that.
Thank you!